# How to allow only certain people to make my phone ring on silent mode?

Tags: audio, calls, silent-mode, alerts

I usually sleep with my cellphone on silent mode, but some important people are allowed to wake me up whenever they want. When it's not on silent mode, some inconvenient people usually wake me up for nothing.

Is there a way to make a call filter and allow only these important people to make my phone ring?

Answer (score 0):

The short of it in Tasker is to create a new profile as follows:

### New Profile:

Context: Time

- From: 22:00
- To: 6:30

Context: State> Phone Call

- Type: Incoming
- Number: C:FAV  (This is any starred contact, You can also list specific contacts if you like)

### Task

New Action: Audio Setting > Ringer Volume

- Level: 7

### Exit Task

New Action: Audio Setting> Silent Mode

- Mode: On

I will try to update later with screenshots and more in depth walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without an app. Set your default ringtone to silent for all calls. Then choose certain contacts and assign them a custom ringtone. Never put your phone on silent mode, all calls will be silent except the contacts you customized.